# Установка flask-socketsio в виртуальное окружение

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

По долгу службы возникла необходимость работы с сокетами. Выбор пал на **flask** + **flask-socketsIO**. Работал по вот [этой статье](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent) и застопорился сразу на установке flask-socketsIO в виртуальное окружение. Лог команды `pip install flask-socketsio` довольно большой, поэтому выкладываю наиболее интересные на мой взгляд части:

```
 Running setup.py install for gevent
    Running '/bin/sh /home/canadien/.python_environments/sock/build/gevent/libev/configure > configure-output.txt' in /home/canadien/.python_environments/sock/build/gevent/build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/libev
    building 'gevent.core' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DLIBEV_EMBED=1 -DEV_COMMON= -DEV_CLEANUP_ENABLE=0 -DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 -DEV_PERIODIC_ENABLE=0 -Ibuild/temp.linux-i686-2.7/libev -Ilibev -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c gevent/gevent.core.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/gevent/gevent.core.o
    gevent/gevent.core.c:17:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /home/canadien/.python_environments/sock/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/canadien/.python_environments/sock/build/gevent/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ft2r5F-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/canadien/.python_environments/sock/include/site/python2.7:
    running install
<...>
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/gevent

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DLIBEV_EMBED=1 -DEV_COMMON= -DEV_CLEANUP_ENABLE=0 -DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 -DEV_PERIODIC_ENABLE=0 -Ibuild/temp.linux-i686-2.7/libev -Ilibev -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c gevent/gevent.core.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/gevent/gevent.core.o

gevent/gevent.core.c:17:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/canadien/.python_environments/sock/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/canadien/.python_environments/sock/build/gevent/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ft2r5F-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/canadien/.python_environments/sock/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/canadien/.python_environments/sock/build/gevent
Storing debug log for failure in /home/canadien/.pip/pip.log
```

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не самой плохой практикой является гуглить прямо весь текст ошибки. В данном случае это

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Многочисленные обсуждения на stackoverflow помогут понять что происходит, а советы вроде

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
```

скорее всего, решат все проблемы.

Comment: да я давно решил проблему, забыл ответ запостить и закрыть вопрос.